# rabbitmq: act on old messages

Tags: rabbitmq, client, reconnect

I have a rabbitmq server that has already sent out a bunch of messages to the queue. If I disconnect a client and reconnect, the client is not reading the old unread messages, rather reading the new ones sent after the client is up for the second time. why? on the surface this does not seem to be related to persistence and durability.

/var/log/rabbitmq/....log:
closing AMQP connection <0.20074.148> (192.168.1.252:39508 -> 192.168.1.1:5672):
client unexpectedly closed TCP connection

remote ssh connection to three machines running the clients was also lost at the same time.

Comment: When you client disconnects, is queue still at the broker?

Comment: yes, because there are clients on other machines receiving messages and there are many more to be received

Comment: If you have multiple clients consuming from the queue, I assume this a work queue as described [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html) ?

Comment: trying out worker queue, thanks @Alex, will get back with the outcome

Comment: thanks @Alex, work queue approach has solved this issue.